# How I can set Full Height in PowerApp form made after customizing the SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form, powerapp

When I try to customize a SharePoint Online List form with PowerApps, the form does not opened as full height.

[image]

When I try to set the custom Height from File -> Settings -> Custom, it give result like

[image]

When I work with high resolution this doesn't look good.

How can I set it to auto resize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the size of the list form via **File** > **Settings** > **Screen size + orientation**.

Switch Size from “Custom” to “Small” or “Large” and the list form should be in the auto resize mode.

Reference:
[Customize a SharePoint list or library form by using Power Apps (Further customize your form).](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form#further-customize-your-form)

Here’s another post with detailed information on custom list form for your reference:

[Increase the width of the power apps forms and add header.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Increase-the-width-of-the-power-apps-forms-and-add-header/td-p/95302)

Comment: When I am using my browser in 4K resolution it is not resizing also I am customizing default SharePoint form (Not creating a custom form from blank)

Comment: @AakashMaurya The setting is available when customizing default SharePoint list form. However, there doesn’t seem to be any official statement about PowerApps working in high resolution devices. You can check out this post and see if you can get custom form height to work with Flexible Height Gallery:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Flexible-Height-Gallery-a-Better-Way/m-p/288986

Comment: This is a known bug, but hasn't been fixed by MS.